# The inside of graves IS or ARE dark?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

1. You can watch movies with projector in your grave because the inside of graves *is* dark.
2. You can watch movies with projector in your grave because the inside of graves *are* dark.

Which verb is appropriate here? Asking this because *graves* is plural.

Comment: I would suggest 'the inside of _a_ grave is dark_'.

Comment: For movie-watching purposes, I suggest that you consider a tomb or, at least, a sepulchre. Graves don't come with much interior space.

Comment: @RonaldSole Spot on. Ha ha. If a grave does not yet contain a body or coffin, it is an open pit. Ergo, with light. These types of questions really take the pits. Oops, piss. Seriously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subject of the clause is "the inside", which is singular and takes "is". The preposition phrase "of graves" is not the subject of the clause, it just modifies "inside".

(I am definitely not asking what you are planning.)

Answer (score 2):

Ditto Jack O'Flaherty: In your sentence as given, it should be "is" because the subject of the verb is "the inside". "Of graves" is a phrase modifying "inside" and is not the subject of the verb, so the fact that "graves" is plural is irrelevant.

That said, it is, perhaps, somewhat odd to refer to the "inside", singular, of many "graves", plural. I would have written, "... the inside of a grave ..." or "the insides of graves ...". But I suppose you could be thinking of graves in a collective sense.

Also, side note, it should be "with a projector", not "with projector". You need an article in there.